# Click function does not work even though the CSS selector does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a gallery of thumbnails, all with class `.thumb` that are added by a `php` code that a friend wrote.  I tried to add a simple click function:

```
$('.thumb').click(function  () {
        console.log('test');
    });
```

And it does not log anything. I had tried this before we switched to `php` as well, and it still didn't work. (At that time the images were imported with `jQuery`)

Below is the relevant `html` code:

```
<div id="navbar">
<img src="images/sig.png">
<ul>
    <li id="port"><a>Portfolio</a></li>
    <ul id="inner">
    <?php
    $dir = opendir("images/portfolio");
        while ($dosya = readdir($dir)){
            if(substr($dosya,-1)!="." and is_dir("images/portfolio/".$dosya)){
                    if(file_get_contents("images/portfolio/".$dosya."/active.dl") == 'active'){

    ?>
        <li class="galleryActivator" cats="<?=$dosya?>"><a href="#"><?=file_get_contents("images/portfolio/".$dosya."/name.dl")?></a></li>

    <?php }} 
        }?>
    </ul>
    <li><li><a href="#">Events</a></li></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="main">
<div id="thumbnails">
</div>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
(function(){
    $('#inner').hide();
    $('#main').hide();
    $('#slideshow').hide();

    $('#port').click(function(){
        $('#inner').slideToggle(200);
        console.log('test');
    });

    $('.galleryActivator').click(function () {
        $("#main").hide();
        $("#main img").remove();

        var category = $(this).attr('cats');
        var catSrc = "images/portfolio/" + category + "/files/";
        var size = $(this).attr("data-size");
        console.log(size);

        var $thumbnails = $("#thumbnails");


            $thumbnails.load( "albumler.php?adres="+category );



        $('#main').fadeIn(200);
    });

    $('.thumb').click(function  () {
        console.log('test');
    });

})();
```

Comment: Where is the `.thumb` class?

Comment: Assuming you actually have an element with that class, you know you don't really have a DOM ready handler, and what you've got is just an IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are loading your thumbnails dynamically; you should set your event handler like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".thumb", function  () {
    console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you dont have anything in your above HTML with a class of `thumb`

but once you do just add document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

    $('.thumb').click(function  () {
        console.log('test');
    });

});
```

Comment: why? Thats the answer

Comment: It's not, the code does not run on `document.ready`, so if the script is loaded before all elements are loaded (e.g. in the `<head>`), it will still fail.

Comment: It is added via php, once a category under portfolio is clicked.

Comment: ok ok, relax, i added in the doc ready part. Im just saying, if you dont have the class it's not going to work. And @sodiumnitrate you should have specified that it was getting added via php

Comment: @sodiumnitrate - added via PHP how exactly? Added with PHP implies a page reload, are you by any chance adding these elements with ajax?

Comment: @adeneo I asked my friend who wrote it, and he says they're loaded with ajax. I am sorry, but I have no idea about php. I can ask my friend anything you need to know, though.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate - Then you have to do `$(document).on('click', '.thumb', function  () { ...`